# A fast method for comparing a value in one Panda’s row to another in a previous row?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a DataFrame, df, that looks like:

```
ID    |          TERM       |   DISC_1
1     |         2003-10     |   ECON
1     |         2002-01     |   ECON
1     |         2002-10     |   ECON
2     |         2003-10     |   CHEM
2     |         2004-01     |   CHEM 
2     |         2004-10     |   ENGN
2     |         2005-01     |   ENGN
3     |         2001-01     |   HISTR
3     |         2002-10     |   HISTR 
3     |         2002-10     |   HISTR
```

ID is a student ID, TERM is an academic term, and DISC_1 is the discipline of their major.  For each student, I’d like to identify the TERM when (and if) they changed DISC_1, and then create a new DataFrame that reports when. Zero indicates they did not change. The output looks like:

```
ID    |     Change
1     |         0     
2     |         2004-01    
3     |         0
```

My code below works, but it’s very slow. I tried to do this using Groupby, but was unable to.  Could someone explain how I might accomplish this task more efficiently?

```
df = df.sort_values(by = ['PIDM', 'TERM'])
c = 0
last_PIDM = 0
last_DISC_1 = 0
change = [ ]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    c = c + 1
    if c > 1:
        row['change'] = np.where((row['PIDM'] == last_PIDM) & (row['DISC_1'] != last_DISC_1),     row['TERM'], 0)
        last_PIDM = row['PIDM']
        last_DISC_1 = row['DISC_1']

    else:
        row['change'] = 0
    change.append(row['change'])  

df['change'] = change        
change_terms = df.groupby('PIDM')['change'].max()
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the `TERM` values.  Does `YYYY-10` come before `YYYY-01`?  Your expected output seems to indicate so, otherwise ID 2 would have multiple switches.  However, your working code does a sort on `TERM` as is, which would give the opposite ordering within years.

Comment: @root yes that was a mistake. At the last minute I changed the dates to make it clear why I needed to sort the column. I corrected the table, ID 2 only has one switch. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a start:

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'TERM'])
gb = df.groupby('ID').DISC_1
df['Change'] = df.TERM[gb.apply(lambda x: x != x.shift().bfill())]
df.Change = df.Change.fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've never been a big pandas user, so my solution would involve spitting that df out as a csv, and iterating over each row, while retaining the previous row. If it is properly sorted (first by ID, then by Term date) I might write something like this...

```
import csv

with open('inputDF.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    with open('outputDF.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)

        previousline = reader.next()  #grab the first row to compare to the second
        termChange = 0
        for line in reader:
            if line[0] != previousline[0]:  #new ID means print and move on to next person
                writer.writerow([previousline[0], termChange])  #print to file ID, termChange date
                termChange = 0
            elif line[2] != previousline[2]:  #new discipline
                termChange = line[1]  #set term changed date
                #termChange = previousline[1]  #in case you want to rather retain the last date they were in the old dicipline

            previousline = line  #store current line as previous and continue loop
```

Comment: I should like to point out also that the reader and writer objects take any iterable object, not just file objects. This means that actual file reading and writing need not occur, and this could simply reside in memory. If you were to do that you would likely need to specify the `dialect=` keyword within both the reader and writer constructors

Comment: sauce: [csv — CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)